# Sending a DM to a specific Discord user

Tags: python, discord, bots, discord.py

I am a noob and trying to create a bot that sends a DM to a specific user, but it returns with the following error: `TypeError: event() missing 1 required positional argument: 'coro'`

```py
import discord
import asyncio
import os
from users import user_list

key = open("ID.txt","r").readline()

bot = discord.Client()

@bot.event()
async def DM(ctx, user: user_list, *, message=None):
    message = "Come show some love and support to our local streamer by giving him a follow here https://www.twitch.tv/streamer"
    await user.send(message)

bot.run(key.strip())
```

Any help would be greatly  appreciated thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_message(self, message):
        if message.author.bot:
            return
        if isinstance(message.channel, discord.DMChannel):    #CHECKS IF MESSAGE IS IN DM
            owner = self.bot.get_user(110877011584503808)
            print(
                f"{message.author.name}#{message.author.discriminator} <{message.author.id}>: {message.content}"
            )
            await owner.send(
                f"{message.author.name}#{message.author.discriminator} <{message.author.id}>: {message.content}"
            )   #SENDS THE MESSAGE SENT TO THE BOT, TO THE OWNER
```

This is my code for when someone sends a dm to my bot.. it will send that persons name and message to me ina dm

owner = self.bot.get_user(110877011584503808) #defines the user you want to send the dm to.    **Change this to a variable with the whatever method you wonna use to grad a user id - if its not a defined user id like mine

then  await owner.send    sends it to that person you have the user.id set to.

```
@bot.command()
async def dm(ctx, user: discord.Member):
    await user.send("Come show some love and support to our local streamer by giving him a follow here https://www.twitch.tv/streamer")
```

Comment: This is abit confusing to me and not sure if it is what I need a bot todo. I need a bot (not a selfbot) that can send messages in DM to a user which I specify. @Trielice

Comment: This command is run thru a cog.  which a little different then just using the bot.py 
I was just trying to show the core features.
````
@bot.command():
async def dm(ctx, user: discord.User, *, message)
    owner = discord.get_user(user.id)
    await user.send(message.content)````

Comment: Thank you @Trielice, this is the response I get when updated the code to your example: ```await user.send(message.content)
                                   ^
TabError: inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation```

Comment: I am at work and writing in the text box sucks..    you will have to type it out and use tabs.. as i am useing spaces here.   and change that message.content   to the msg u had before..   unless u want to pass through a different msg every time

Comment: it seems to be complaining about the bracket and not whatever is inside the brackets or indendation - see image https://ibb.co/hs4wbSt and you can see the code here: https://pastebin.pl/view/689d52b7

Comment: @bot.command()
async def dm(ctx, user: discord.Member):
    await user.send("Come show some love and support to our local streamer by giving him a follow here https://www.twitch.tv/streamer")

Updated my resonse again.. i have tested this on my RDP

Just  <prefix>dm @personsname

Comment: Also i recommend learning to make Embeds..  way more sexy then general text
my discord is Trielice#3492 if u need help

Answer (score 0):

Given the code & other answer I feel obliged to give you a full example here using the [commands framework](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/index.html)

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

with open("ID.txt", 'r') as f:
    key = f.readline()

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')

@bot.command()
async def dm(ctx, user: discord.User, *, message=None):
    message = message or "Come show some love and support to our local streamer by giving him a follow here https://www.twitch.tv/streamer"
    await user.send(message)

bot.run(key.strip())
```

This can be run using `!dm <user> [message]` to send a dm to whoever you mention

Comment: Used your code above exactly and got the following error:   ```File "messenger.py", line 11
    async def dm(ctx, user: discord.User, *, message=None)
                                                         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax```

Comment: Fixed, forgot semicolon